# PHP CURL MP4 file headers

Tags: php, curl, header, mp4

I am using a HTML5 player to play a video on website, the video is grabbed from CDN. By Using CURL I am getting the file from CDN but when I try to play that in browser I am not able to play it, so I think that headers are not set properly for the file.

Here is my code:

```
if (!empty($path) && $path != null)
        {
            $ch = curl_init($path);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            if ($data === false)
            {
                echo 'CURL Failed';
                exit;
            }

            if (preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches))
            {
                $contentLength = (int) $matches[1];
            }

            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Content-Length: ' . $contentLength);
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            echo $data;
            exit;
        }
```

Are the headers set properly to play a MP4 file? Cause when I hit the URL video is not played. The video file is MP4 and I am trying to play this file in chrome(chrome supports mp4 file). The direct URL access to file is `http://moviese.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/test7.mp4`

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid, but why exactly would you use a CDN for a file you're getting with CURL on the serverside ?

Comment: for security reasons I cant explore CDN path to the user directly

Comment: But then using a CDN is pointless ?

Comment: You have a VIDEO player, and you ask whether "AUDIO/mpeg" is the correct mime type?

Comment: `audio/mpeg` is a typo mistake, please check now